# VB.NET How to display a msgbox if no radiobuttons were checked?

Tags: vb.net, radio-button, msgbox

Im creating a Payment Method, but im unsure how to display a msgbox when none of the Radiobuttons are checked.

This is my current code.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If RadioButton1.Checked Then Paypal_Pay.Show()
    Me.Hide()

    If RadioButton2.Checked Then PayWave_Pay.Show()
    Me.Hide()

    If RadioButton3.Checked Then CreditCard_Pay.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

But im unsure how to implement the msgbox in when the user doesn't check any of the radiobuttons.
Sidenote- If the User clicks the Button and doesn't check any of the button, it just crashes.. so im unsure how to fix that.

Comment: This is a classic case of a beginner not breaking a problem down into smaller parts. The `MsgBox` is irrelevant and is just clouding your thinking. It doesn't matter what you want to do. The actual part that matters is determining that no `RadioButtons` are checked and, given that each `Checked` property is just a `Boolean`, your problem boils down to how to determine that none of multiple `Boolean` expressions is `True`. Nothing at all to do with `RadioButtons` or `MsgBox`. This is why beginners have trouble solving problems: they try to solve the wrong problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `If..ElseIf` to test each RadioButton, and then have a final `Else` to display the MsgBox, eg:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  If RadioButton1.Checked Then
    Paypal_Pay.Show()
    Me.Hide()
  ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked Then
    PayWave_Pay.Show()
    Me.Hide()
  ElseIf RadioButton3.Checked Then
    CreditCard_Pay.Show()
    Me.Hide()
  Else
    MsgBox(...)
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, Thankyou for helping out!

Comment: @bruhjuice Please accept the answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.